# Bootstrap - NavBar is not collapsing well first element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a responsive navbar. It is working fine in large windows but when I put it in a xs screen it is not collapsing well the fist element of the nabar. 
I put an exemple of the two cases:

First case, it's working fine: 
[image]

And this is the second case: 
[image]

Why is the "HOME" Not colapsing?

I attach the code of the html and the css code:

```css
html {
  background: url(Fondo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  /*Poner foto de fondo. */
  background-size: cover;
  /*Para que la foto ocupe toda la pantalla*/
  overflow-y: auto;
  /*Para que salga scroollbar cuando se hace zoom*/
  /*overflow-x:auto;*/
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  /*Tipo de letra en todo el documento*/
}

body {
  background: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  /*Estas dos lineas son para que la navbar este pegada arriba*/
  padding: 0 !important;
}

h2 {
  color: #4CAF50;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

button:hover {
  /* Que sucede cuando se coloca raton encima de boton */
  opacity: 0.8;
}

span.psw {
  float: right;
  /*padding-top: 16px;*/
}

.blue-column {
  background-color: #D1E4F2;
  opacity: 0.8;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 5px;
  /**Para que el titutlo este un poco separado del margen azul de arriba*/
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.piedepagina {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  height: 27px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2794DE;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.piedepaginaInside {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.navbar li a {
  color: #ffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login</title>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" , charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #045186;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar2">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white" href="#">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a style="color: white" href="Login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"style="color: white"></span> Iniciar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a style="color: white" href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>


  <div class="container-fluid " style="background:none">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <!-- El offset es para centrar la columna en el medio de la pantalla-->
        <div class="blue-column">
          <label for="uname"><b>Usuario</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce el usuario" name="uname" id="uname">

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Introduce el password" name="psw" id="psw">
          <div class="center-block text-center">
            <input type="radio" name="tipousuario" value="corredor" id="tipousuario"> Corredor
            <input type="radio" name="tipousuario" value="voluntario" id="tipousuario"> Voluntario<br>
          </div>
          <button id="login" value="Login" onclick="post();">Iniciar Sesion</button>
          <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Recordarme"> Recordarme
                </label>
          <label>
                  <span class="psw"><a href="#">Olvido la contraseña?</a></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <footer class="piedepagina">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i><i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"> </i><i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"> </i><i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <p class="piedepaginaInside">Powered by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/victor-dorado-fern%C3%A1ndez-03b842105/" target="_blank">Victor Dorado</a></p>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance for the help!!

PD: In fact i want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Isn't it because your `home` is outside the `collapse navbar-collapse` div? You should put it there, and inside the `ul`

Comment: No it isn't, it'r not working with this solution

Comment: Try looking at the view point <!DOCTYPE html> <html charset="UTF-8"> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> Think it could have something with this line of code and think of script in answer 1

Comment: I have update the question with the result that I want.

Comment: never do inline styling. https://jsfiddle.net/4qbzvt9c/. You can change your colors depending on your choice.

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Issue is with the style, its applied for button.

You have defined the CSS for button tag and due to this its applied for both login and nav-bar buttons that's y output is not proper.

Please check the below code.

```css
html {
    background: url(Fondo.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;  /*Poner foto de fondo. */
    background-size:cover;                                     /*Para que la foto ocupe toda la pantalla*/
    overflow-y:auto;                                           /*Para que salga scroollbar cuando se hace zoom*/
    /*overflow-x:auto;*/
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;                 /*Tipo de letra en todo el documento*/
    }

body{
  background:none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;         /*Estas dos lineas son para que la navbar este pegada arriba*/
  padding: 0 !important;
}

h2{
    color:#4CAF50;
}

label{
    font-weight:bold;
}


input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  button.login{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
  }

  button.login:hover{                                /* Que sucede cuando se coloca raton encima de boton */
    opacity: 0.8;
  }


  span.psw {  
    float: right;
    /*padding-top: 16px;*/
  }

  .blue-column {
    background-color: #D1E4F2;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display:block;
    padding-top: 5px;/**Para que el titutlo este un poco separado del margen azul de arriba*/
    padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;

  }

  .piedepagina{
    position:fixed;
    left:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    height:27px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #2794DE;
    text-align: center;
    float: right; 
    font-size: 10px;

  }
  .piedepaginaInside{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;

  }


.navbar li a {
  color: #ffff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .columns {
      width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Login</title>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" , charset="UTF-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" style="background-color: #045186;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar2"
        area-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="color: white" href="#">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="myNavbar2">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a style="color: white" href="Login.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"style="color: white"></span> Iniciar Sesion</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a style="color: white" href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <br>


  <div class="container-fluid " style="background:none">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <!-- El offset es para centrar la columna en el medio de la pantalla-->
        <div class="blue-column">
          <label for="uname"><b>Usuario</b></label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Introduce el usuario" name="uname" id="uname">

          <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Introduce el password" name="psw" id="psw">
          <div class="center-block text-center">
            <input type="radio" name="tipousuario" value="corredor" id="tipousuario"> Corredor
            <input type="radio" name="tipousuario" value="voluntario" id="tipousuario"> Voluntario<br>
          </div>
          <button id="login" class="login" value="Login" onclick="post();">Iniciar Sesion</button>
          <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="Recordarme"> Recordarme
                </label>
          <label>
                  <span class="psw"><a href="#">Olvido la contraseña?</a></span>
                </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

  <footer class="piedepagina">
    <i class="fa fa-facebook-official w3-hover-opacity"></i><i class="fa fa-instagram w3-hover-opacity"> </i><i class="fa fa-twitter w3-hover-opacity"> </i><i class="fa fa-linkedin w3-hover-opacity"></i>
    <p class="piedepaginaInside">Powered by <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/victor-dorado-fern%C3%A1ndez-03b842105/" target="_blank">Victor Dorado</a></p>
  </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I have given the class for your login button and separate the CSS style applied for login button from the nav-bar button.

Here is the updated output

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works, but one question: Why the button is grey instead of green when in the butoon .login css class the background is setted to green?

Comment: I glad that it worked for you, actually, had given the solution of the question asked, so didnt validate the rest CSS, anyways the issue was, space between button and login in CSS, have removed that space and also change the hover CSS to get the proper result. If solution works for you, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your home link is not inside the `collapse navbar-collapse` div.

Here's the corrected [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lw8czsdm/):

Comment: I copy your solution and the nabvar is not working, I mean it does not open down

Comment: I have update the question with the result that I want.